# Is being maimed a bad thing?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I got in a fight, and ended up a tad maimed. What effect does this actually have? I seem to be up and about as normal, but I'm assuming there's got to be *something* bad...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Maimed is bad

It reduces the character's accuracy and **all** defensive stats by 15. It leaves the character with a single health and endurance point.

[image: maimed status tooltip 1]

More importantly, **if a maimed character loses that health point, they die.**

[image: maimed glossary definition]

Since their defenses are crippled and enemies have a penchant for going after weak targets, chances are the character will not survive another combat.

## How to Cure Maimed? Sleep it off

If you want to save the maimed character, avoid combat until the party can rest by making camp or getting to an inn.

## How does this work with permadeath?

If you are playing with the permadeath option, *there is no maimed status*. Characters die as soon as they reach 0 health points.